# create image from HTML templates ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

I found 100s of post here and google which discuss this type… creating image from html but didn’t find any solution to my problem.

I am working with an application that creates HTML ads at run time using certain templates. I need to save images of each ad. The HTML ads (shown as HTML page) come up great... How do I save/capture this add into an image?  I am developing in ASP.NET

My research pointed me to using WebRequest method to get the page and then getting the byte[] from it to save that to image...WHICH FAILS ...cause HTML comes as text and is not formatted as yet (until displayed in browser).... Secondly I got interesting results which used HTML5 Canvas element... Sadly my application is not in HTML5... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebBrowser control(which uses IE engine, I guess):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

...

using(var browser = new WebBrowser())
{
    browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    browser.Navigate("www.example.com");
    while(browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) 
    { 
        Application.DoEvents(); 
    }
    browser.Width = browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
    browser.Height = browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;

    var bitmap = new Bitmap(browser.Width, browser.Height);
    browser.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, browser.Width, browser.Height));
    bitmap.Save("filename");
}
```